# Powershell PSCX Write-Zip "Extra data extended Zip64 information length is invalid"

Tags: powershell, zip

I'm facing an issue with write-zip : The second time I call Write-Zip with -Append parameter I get an error : Extra data extended Zip64 information length is invalid.

I'm using PSCX 2.1.x.

I got around the issue by creating a function that, rather than appending a new file, expends the existing zip if any to a temp folder, adds the new file to the folder, and then zip all files in one time.
That works... but it is not very efficient.

Is there any solution ?

Here is my working function :

```
Function Add-To-Zip {
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String] $Path,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String] $OutputPath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String] $TempPath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
    [Boolean] $RemoveOriginal = $False
)

If (Test-Path $TempPath) {
    Remove-Item -Path $TempPath -Recurse
}
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $TempPath

$paths = @()

Copy-Item $Path $TempPath

If (Test-Path $OutputPath) {        
    Expand-Archive -Path $OutputPath -OutputPath $TempPath
}

Get-ChildItem $TempPath | ForEach { $paths += Get-Item $_.FullName }

Try {
    $paths | Write-Zip -OutputPath $OutputPath -Quiet -FlattenPaths -EntryPathRoot $TempPath

    If ($RemoveOriginal) {
        Remove-Item -Path $Path
    }
} Catch {
    Throw "An error occured while adding '$FilePath' to '$ZipPath'."
}

If (Test-Path $TempPath) {
    Remove-Item -Path $TempPath -Recurse
}
}
```

Comment: I seem to recall that there have been fixes to ZIP file handling in recent versions of PSCX. And V2.1.x is quite old, the current version is 3.2: can you re-create in the latest version?

Comment: The problem is that this 3.2 version targets Powershell 3+... and my production environment only supports Powershell 2...

Comment: A failure to re-create in V3.x (in an isolated environment) would help root cause to a PSCX limitation or defect. At that point possibilities become clearer.